# SELECT Statement in CASE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Please don't downgrade this as it is bit complex for me to explain.  I'm working on data migration so some of the structures look weird because it was designed by someone like that.

For ex, I have a table Person with PersonID and PersonName as columns.  I have duplicates in the table.

I have Details table where I have PersonName stored in a column. This PersonName may or may not exist in the Person table. I need to retrieve PersonID from the matching records otherwise put some hardcode value in PersonID.

I can't write below query because PersonName is duplicated in Person Table, this join doubles the rows if there is a matching record due to join.

```
SELECT d.Fields, PersonID
FROM Details d
JOIN Person p ON d.PersonName = p.PersonName
```

The below query works but I don't know how to replace "NULL" with some value I want in place of NULL

```
SELECT d.Fields, (SELECT TOP 1 PersonID FROM Person where PersonName = d.PersonName )
FROM Details d
```

So, there are some PersonNames in the Details table which are not existent in Person table.  How do I write CASE WHEN in this case?

I tried below but it didn't work

```
 SELECT d.Fields, 
       CASE WHEN (SELECT TOP 1 PersonID 
                 FROM Person 
                 WHERE PersonName = d.PersonName) = null 
       THEN 123 
       ELSE (SELECT TOP 1 PersonID 
              FROM Person 
              WHERE PersonName = d.PersonName) END Name
    FROM Details d
```

This query is still showing the same output as 2nd query.  Please advise me on this.  Let me know, if I'm unclear anywhere.  Thanks

Comment: `= null` will never evaluate to true, you need to say `IS NULL`. Also the pattern you're using is inefficient and unintuitive. You should try an outer join instead of all these verbose subqueries.

Comment: It's a bad habit to write subqueries like this: `(SELECT TOP 1 PersonID FROM Person where PersonName = d.PersonName )` - try to get into the habit of using aliases inside them - `(SELECT TOP 1 p.PersonID FROM Person p where p.PersonName = d.PersonName )` - if you get column names incorrect, but the same column exists in the outer query, it will be used without warning and this is usually incorrect (e.g. if there was no `PersonName` column in `Person`, your `WHERE` clause effectively turns into `where d.PersonName = d.PersonName`)

Comment: thanks Damien for the valuable point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple left outer join to pull back all persons with an optional match on the details table should work with a case statement to get your desired result.

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        Instance=ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PersonName),
        PersonID=CASE WHEN d.PersonName IS NULL THEN 'XXXX' ELSE p.PersonID END,
        d.Fields
    FROM
        Person p
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Details d on d.PersonName=p.PersonName
)AS X
WHERE
   Instance=1
```

Comment: Note that this will return multiple rows for any person with more than one Details row.

Comment: there are multiple rows in Details table so I can't use any join to trust here.

Answer (score 2):

well.. I figured I can put ISNULL on top of SELECT to make it work.

```
SELECT d.Fields, 
    ISNULL(SELECT TOP 1 p.PersonID 
           FROM Person p where p.PersonName = d.PersonName, 124) id
    FROM Details d
```

Comment: *In general*, prefer [`COALESCE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms190349.aspx) over `ISNULL` - it generalizes to more than 2 inputs, it uses the normal data type precedence rules, and it's standard SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Ooh goody, a chance to use two `LEFT JOIN`s. The first will list the IDs where they exist, and insert a default otherwise; the second will eliminate the duplicates.

```
   SELECT d.Fields, ISNULL(p1.PersonID, 123)
     FROM Details d
LEFT JOIN Person p1 ON d.PersonName = p1.PersonName
LEFT JOIN Person p2 ON p2.PersonName = p1.PersonName
                   AND p2.PersonID < p1.PersonID
    WHERE p2.PersonID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use common table expressions to build up the missing datasets, i.e. your complete Person table, then join that to your Detail table as follows;

```
declare @n int;
-- set your default PersonID here;
set @n = 123;

-- Make sure previous SQL statement is terminated with semilcolon for with clause to parse successfully.

-- First build our unique list of names from table Detail.
with cteUniqueDetailPerson
(
    [PersonName]
)
as
(
    select distinct [PersonName]
    from [Details]
)

-- Second get unique Person entries and record the most recent PersonID value as the active Person.
, cteUniquePersonPerson
(
      [PersonID]
    , [PersonName]
)
as
(
    select
          max([PersonID]) -- if you wanted the original Person record instead of the last, change this to min.
        , [PersonName]
    from [Person]
    group by [PersonName]
)

-- Third join unique datasets to get the PersonID when there is a match, otherwise use our default id @n.
-- NB, this would also include records when a Person exists with no Detail rows (they are filtered out with the final inner join)
, cteSudoPerson
(
      [PersonID]
    , [PersonName]
)
as
(
    select
        coalesce(upp.[PersonID],@n) as [PersonID]
        coalesce(upp.[PersonName],udp.[PersonName]) as [PersonName]
    from cteUniquePersonPerson upp
    full outer join cteUniqueDetailPerson udp
        on udp.[PersonName] = p.[PersonName]
)

-- Fourth, join detail to the sudo person table that includes either the original ID or our default ID.
select
      d.[Fields]
    , sp.[PersonID]
from [Details] d
inner join cteSudoPerson sp
    on sp.[PersonName] = d.[PersonName];
```